# How to make dual boot live dvd

Tags: linux, livecd

Can we make a live dvd with a dual boot option between Ubuntu and Linux mint?

I have both the iso's. They both are larger than 800mb. If I will burn 2 dvd's, Then a lot of space will be wasted. So I wanted to make one live cd that can boot both of them.

I have searched the net but did not find any result.

Comment: first hit on google: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/12/create-bootable-iso-with-multiple-linux.html

Comment: But I have to make it with windows. This works on linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used Sardu for that job. It allows you to create a multiboot DVD and you choose the distroes you would like to multi boot into. It involves downloading the distros and this program will then boot thse distroes.

Details [here](http://www.sarducd.it/) the process is detailed but its worth the trouble.

Comment: I have found a tool called Xboot: https://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/